# how to check file is opened from python scrip

Tags: python, perforce, p4python

I need to check file is opened in perforce or not like this:

```
if((p4.run("opened", self.file) != True):
```

but it's not the right way I think it's always true
can you please help to solve this
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p4.run("opened")` returns a list of results (dicts) corresponding to open files, which will be empty if no files are opened within the path specification you provided.  Try just printing out the value, or better yet running it in the REPL, to get a better understanding of what the function returns:

```
>>> from P4 import P4
>>> p4 = P4()
>>> p4.connect()
P4 [Samwise@Samwise-dvcs-1509687817 rsh:p4d.exe -i -r "c:\Perforce\test\.p4root"] connected
>>> p4.run("opened", "//...")
[{'depotFile': '//stream/test/foo', 'clientFile': '//Samwise-dvcs-1509687817/foo', 'rev': '2', 'haveRev': '2', 'action': 'edit', 'change': 'default', 'type': 'text', 'user': 'Samwise', 'client': 'Samwise-dvcs-1509687817'}]
>>> p4.run("opened", "//stream/test/foo")
[{'depotFile': '//stream/test/foo', 'clientFile': '//Samwise-dvcs-1509687817/foo', 'rev': '2', 'haveRev': '2', 'action': 'edit', 'change': 'default', 'type': 'text', 'user': 'Samwise', 'client': 'Samwise-dvcs-1509687817'}]
>>> p4.run("opened", "//stream/test/bar")
[]
```

We can see that running `p4 opened //stream/test/foo` gives us a list containing one file (because `foo` is open for edit), and `p4 opened //stream/test/bar` gives us an empty list (because `bar` is not open for anything).

In Python a list is "falsey" if empty and "truthy" if non-empty.  This is not the same as being `== False` and `== True`, but it does work in most other contexts where a boolean is expected, including `if` statements and the `not` operator:

```
>>> if p4.run("opened", "//stream/test/foo"):
...     print("foo is open")
...
foo is open
>>> if not p4.run("opened", "//stream/test/bar"):
...     print("bar is not open")
...
bar is not open
```

It's considered perfectly Pythonic to use lists in this way (it's why the concept of "truthiness" exists in the language) instead of using explicit `True`/`False` values.

If you do need an exact `True` or `False` value (e.g. to return from a function that is declared as returning an exact boolean value), you can use the `bool` function to convert a truthy value into `True` and a falsey value into `False`:

```
>>> bool(p4.run("opened", "//stream/test/foo"))
True
>>> bool(p4.run("opened", "//stream/test/bar"))
False
```

or use a `len()` comparison, which amounts to the same thing:

```
>>> len(p4.run("opened", "//stream/test/foo")) > 0
True
>>> len(p4.run("opened", "//stream/test/bar")) > 0
False
```